# About MQTT plug-in of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, mqtt

I installed a virtual machine(ubuntu 14) on the MACBOOK by parallels desktop.

I want to install MQTT plug-in of apache-jmeter-2.13 on ubuntu 14.

I have already installed MQTT plug-in,and Update the file messages.properties in the folder `:/org/apache/jmeter/resources/` in ApacheJMeter_core.jar by new file messages.properties from https://github.com/tuanhiep/mqtt-jmeter/tree/master/ressource, but when I open Jmeter,there is not MQTT plug-in in sampler of Jmeter.

Why?How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I have resolved this questions.Everything I do is all right.A virtual machine itself has a Jmeter that version is 2.8.But I do all the things on Jmeter about 2.13.Oh I'm so sorry,I made a stupid mistake。